# Sprinkler pump runs to repressurize tank even when pump timer is in OFF position

Tags: electrical, well-pump

Sprinkler timer is in OFF position and the pump still runs to pressurize the sprinkler pressure tank.  Runs about 20 secs. but at all hours of the day.

Comment: Brand/model? Some sort of detail to go on is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a leak in your system. Fix it, and the pump will stop running when the system isn't calling for water.

Or change the system so it shuts off the pump power when not irrigating, if the pump is only for the irrigation system.

If the pump is only running 20 seconds, the pressure tank either has a failed bladder or is about 3 times too small. Minimum run time with no water being used should be 60 seconds for best pump life.

Comment: See *e.g.* https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/169484/18078 about checking the tank bladder.

Comment: How would I wire the pump to be totally OFF the power supply when the sprinkler timer is in the off position?

Comment: Typically you'd use some signal from the controller to energize the coil of a relay that is rated for the power of the pump motor.

Comment: You could also add an electrically operated valve close to the pump, to isolate the leaking portion (presumably not right there or you'd see a puddle.) If you have a manual shutoff valve for the pump, use it. If it continues to run intermittently without a puddle, you have a leak on the intake (well) side of the system.